# open gl depth buffer issue

Tags: c, opengl

I have a simple Opengl programm where I draw triangles by calling glVertex3f and the mode GL_LINE_LOOP

here's what I get:

[image]

You can see in the square that apparently some triangles that are at the base of my model (in blue) are drawn above what is in the foreground.

Do you know what is causing it? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: What is your depth range (minz and maxz). How are you setting up the projection matrix?

Comment: @doug65536 do you mean this?
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
  gluPerspective(60., Width/Height,0,1000);

Comment: @lezebulon: a near plane at distance 0 cannot really work with perspective projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> gluPerspective(60., Width/Height,0,1000);

The near-z cannot be 0 or less. It must be a positive number greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

The near Z cannot be zero. See [the opengl.org documentation for gluPerspective](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml).

The relevant part:

> Depth buffer precision is affected by the values specified for zNear
>   and zFar. The greater the ratio of zFar to zNear is, the less
>   effective the depth buffer will be at distinguishing between surfaces
>   that are near each other.
>
> If *r = zFar / zNear*, roughly *log2(r)* bits of depth buffer precision are lost. Because *r* approaches
>   infinity as zNear approaches 0, zNear must never be set to 0.